# 2 ES clusters or 1

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation

So i have been setting up opensource search engine commonsearch for past few days.

They have a buggy development kit, but i fixed the bugs and finally run succesfful execution.

But here's the trick.

Here in architecture documentation - https://about.commonsearch.org/developer/architecture

They are saying that there are 2 clusters of ES.

but here on deployment of the project: https://about.commonsearch.org/developer/operations

They say that there are 1 cluster and 3 nodes.

After running the strict, i dont see any ES clusters, only 3 EC2 instances like theyr documentation described. Where do i connect my frontend to ?

Has some has ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to ignore the indice structure and just create 2 AWS clusters and import data there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm correct, all of them most be pointing to one IP address, if not, use the IP of the master node.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for idea tho!